# Inherited operator= not working?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, operator-overloading

I am overloading `operator=` on a struct `EqualTestBase`, and `operator=` takes different parameters than are used to construct the struct.

```
struct EqualTestBase
{
 EqualTestBase(int one) {}

 EqualTestBase& operator=(std::string two)
 {
  //stuff

  return *this;
 }
};
```

It works fine on the base class.  But a trival struct derived from it, `EqualTestDerived`, acts like it doesn't have the `operator=` member function.

```
struct EqualTestDerived : public EqualTestBase
{
 EqualTestDerived(int one) : EqualTestBase(one) {}
};

void test()
{
 EqualTestBase basetest(0);
 basetest = "test"; //this is fine, compiles

 EqualTestDerived derivedtest(0);
 derivedtest = "test"; //this does not compile, says there is no constructor that takes type const char[5]
}
```

Do I have to redefine `operator=` on all derived structs, or is there a way to automatically pass down that functionality?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The derived class has an implicitly-declared copy-assignment operator, which hides the one declared in the base class. You can use `using` to bring it into scope:

```
struct EqualTestDerived : public EqualTestBase
{
    EqualTestDerived(int one) : EqualTestBase(one) {}
    using EqualTestBase::operator=;
};
```

Comment: I think one should also mention that assignment and class hierarchies are two concepts which usually don't mix well. Typically, if a class has an assignment operator, then it's not a base class, and vice versa.

Comment: @ChristianHackl: If the inheritance is for polymorphism, then you're right; but that's not the case here. (One might argue that composition would be more ideologically pure, if less convenient, than non-polymorphic inheritance; but such philosophical musings are rather off-topic for a simple question like this).

Comment: Well, that's why I said "usually" and "typically" :) I'm just speaking from my own personal experience. When I was new to C++, I would certainly derive a lot of more than needed, and I was exposed to many problems like the OP's because I did not strictly distinguish between derivable and non-derivable classes.

Answer (score 2):

`operator=` isn't inherited. If a class doesn't define `operator=` itself, the compiler will synthesize one for it (regardless of the fact that its base class *does* define an `operator=`).

If you want something that can be inherited (and can be virtual) you generally want to define it as a function with a different name. The generally accepted name for such a function is `clone` (though clone is normally more like a copy constructor, creating a new instance of an object, not just assigning to an existing one).

Comment: Of course it's inherited. It's just hidden by the implicitly-declared version in the derived class.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: While technically true, that seems to me like it's mostly getting into a word game that's unlikely to be of any real help to the OP.

Comment: It certainly would be of help to the OP, since it's simple to unhide it with a using-declaration, as my answer demonstrates. That wouldn't be possible if it weren't inherited for some reason.

Comment: IMO, that's also generally unhelpful. It's simple to un-hide it, but if you're going to show him how to do that, you also need to write (or at least point to) nearly a book about its limitations and the fact that he probably does *not* want to do that, and will probably get entirely incorrect behavior from doing so. In simple terms, you've done the equivalent of "here kid: here's how to turn that into a fully automatic rifle with no safety."

Comment: @JerryCoffin If I wasn't doing it the way Mike said, I would be copying and pasting the function into the derived classes.

Comment: @JerryCoffin: I've no idea what you're talking about. Adding the base-class operator to the set of overloads simply makes it assignable from a string (affecting only the base sub-object) as well as copy-assignable (affecting the whole object). I can't see "entirely incorrect behaviour" there, or any particular "limitations" (whatever you mean by that). The only danger is if the derived class adds data members that also need to be updated when the base class is assigned to, in which case you'd write a new operator (perhaps calling the base-class version) instead of using the inherited one.